# Sinon.js inline callback on success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback, sinon

I'm using QUnit, Sinon.js (fakeServer) and jQuery (AJAX) to capture and test AJAX calls in my program. I'm having an issue (inconsistency) where the inline-function calls do not get executed.

```
$.ajax({
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    async: bAsynchronous,
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: content + getSecurityURL(url,sData), //we need to pass the information for security.
    success: typeof functionA == 'function' && typeof functionB == 'function'
             ? [functionA, functionB] : console.log('Error'),
  });
```

The expected exectuting behavior is `functionA` followed by `functionB`.
It works, **if I write** it `? [functionA(), functionB()] : console.log('Error')` this way. Why does it not work without brackets?

**Edit 1:**
Both functions A & B contain a `console.log('Working!');` I know the code works correctly if I see 2 `Working!` logs in the console. I know that the request succeeds because `server.requests` is not empty and `server.requests[0]` contains all other AJAX call attributes such as: contentType, type, url & data.

Here's what my QUnit set-up code looks like for `sinon` (this intercepts all AJAX calls made during testing):

```
QUnit.module('unit tests', {
    beforeEach: function() {
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    },  
    afterEach: function() {
        delete server;
    }
});
```

Comment: Because you're not calling them.

Comment: @DaveNewton it works in the actual application (outside unit testing).

Comment: My bad-I didn't even know you could do that, but it looks like you can. If they're not being called that would imply that the request isn't succeeding, no?

Comment: The request is succeeding! They don't get 'executed' in the testing scenario. I have a strong feeling that this has to do with Sinon.js (sniffing AJAX post requests and maybe "creating" the functions but not actually running them)

Comment: How do you know? If the functions aren't being called, what indication of success is there? With no error handler, hard to say. In any case, not sure how to help without more info.

Comment: I use a console.log(); inside each function and it's nothing gets printed. I also mention in the question that if I call the function with brackets, they "magically" work. Or if I replace say `functionA` with an `alert('Test');`, it will work.

Comment: That's how you know they *do* work--how do you know the request is succeeding? There's no "magic" why they'd get called if you call them, you're calling them, and putting the result of that call into the array being passed to `success`. If you add an error handler, is that being called in the scenario that's failing?

Comment: @DaveNewton there is an error handler in the real scenario, but it experiences the same behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by my set-up. The AJAX call was **aborting** due to a security configuration (has to do with the url) and therefore did not execute any inline functions. Adding brackets in `[functionA(), functionB()]` only worked because the functions would execute **during** the call, but not as the result of the call. Also, both functions would execute if `typeof functionA == 'function' && typeof functionB == 'function'` returned `true` regardless of whether or not the call actually went through.

I solved the issue by changing a few security configs. Essentially "whitelisting" certain files to be `POSTED` to. Thanks to everyone who helped!